# How many uses of a dynamic value justify making it a variable?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery:

```
        var $activeList = $('.active_list');
        var $activeSlide = $activeList.find('.active_list_slide');
        var slideIndex = $activeList.children().index($activeSlide);
```

In the case above, `$activeList` was used twice. Was it worth it to make it a variable rather than just keeping it as `$('.active_list')`.

My general rule was always that 2 uses of a dynamic variable make it worth it to make a variable (rather than doing the same operation to find it twice). Is this a good philosophy?

Comment: when writing jQuery, the less `$()` calls you make the better. assigning the resulting object to a variable *if its **ever** going to be used again* is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. You'll avoid what is potentially a lot of code execution behind that query. The only exception is if somehow the result might have changed from one call to the next. Doesn't seem very likely in this context, though. This is DOM manipulation, not massively concurrent database updates.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I agree that what you are doing is perfectly sensible. It improves readibility, keeps line length down and also will perform better. The jQuery expression `$('.active_list')` does a non-trivial amount of work and so it makes sense to cache the result in a variable rather than repeat the query.

It also makes your code easier to maintain - if you ever need to change how you retrieve $activeList then you can make the change in one place rather than trying to hunt down every occurrence of `$('.active_list')`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes even one use is enough, if it helps clarify your code. Assigning a name to a complex value is a nice way of making your code self-documenting.